# "written assignment" vs "writing assignment"

Tags: meaning-in-context, terminology

What's the difference between "written assignment" and "writing assignment"?

I was told just now this:

> "...written assignment (is) versus oral assignment, and writing assignment
>   (is) versus reading assignment..."

Does that mean that the difference is not in the definition (both are acts of writing something), but rather in the usage (that is, if the context is oral communication, then it's better to say "written assignment"; and if the context is reading, then it's better to say "writing assignment")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need clarification from the one who assigned the work.

Unfortunately, the *"assignment"* can mean both the *"details of the work to be done"* and the *"work that has been done",* leaving room for confusion.

A **writing assignment** is easily understood as a request for the action of writing *(example: write a paragraph).*

A **reading assignment** is easily understood as a request for the action of reading *(example: read this paragraph).*

A **written assignment** can be understood in two ways: first, as a written request for some action *(example: a note to get groceries);* and second, as a written result or execution of a request *(example: a written paragraph summarizing a story).*

An **oral assignment** can be understood in two ways; first, as an oral request for some action *(example: being told to get groceries);* and second, as an oral result or execution of a request *(example: reciting a poem).*

Comment: WOW! Now I understand. Thank you!